Need some extra pointers on maximizing single instance performance in mockserver
Description:
I'm a backend developer in a company. I've been utilizing a mockserver extensively to facilitate testing of my backend services by returning specific dummy responses. However, I've encountered a bottleneck as I attempt to scale up my testing to handle up to 300M requests per minute.
Objective:
Before proceeding with horizontal scaling by adding multiple pods for the mock server, I aim to maximize the capacity of a single instance to handle a higher volume of requests.
Current Status:
Despite various attempts including increasing memory and CPU allocation, disabling logging, and other methods outlined in the documentation, I haven't been able to surpass 5k requests per second. Additionally, the mock server frequently experiences latency issues and SSL handshake timeouts.
I need pointers on optimizing the capabilities of a single instance before resorting to multiple pods from individuals who have successfully addressed similar challenges in the past. Any insights or recommendations on fine-tuning configurations, tweaking performance parameters, or utilizing advanced techniques to enhance the mock server's responsiveness would be greatly appreciated.
Documentation has been referenced but any shared experiences or best practices in maximizing the efficiency of mock servers in high-velocity testing scenarios outside the documentation would be invaluable.

5M requests/second is an extremely high load. You may not need it unless you are evaluating traffic for Dhoni's inning @ IPL final match!
(1) Are you able to generate this load locally? The issue may not be on the mockserver, but on the client's resources.
(2) The more the CPU usage, the more instability with the server application. Page faults, garbage collectors, memory leak bugs, etc. play important roles in getting a steady and predictable performance. There are multiple mock-servers in the market, which one you are referring to? Java, Nodejs, or Python based?

I suggest you go with a hosted mock server instead of getting stuck in tooling and infra setup. I am building Beeceptor.com do reach out/contact for more detail and discussion.

@ankitjaininfo I tried generating load locally through a Golang program but was hitting bottleneck after 10k req/sec.
Also the mockserver that I'm using is Java based: https://github.com/mock-server/mockserver
